# Is it okay to transfer reputation to another account using bounties?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Let's say I have a new Email adress and make a new Stackexchange account using it. My old account would then be obselete but all my reputatuin is still on my old account. Would it be allowed to use the bounty system to transfer my reputation from my old account to my new account?

Or is there a feature just for that?

Comment: As long as you can still login to your previous account you can change the email address and profile information. Why would this new account be necessary?

Comment: Ok let's change the example: Let's say I make another account which I share with someone. I want to make sure that both me and the other person can e.g. start bounties but don't want to share my current avvount with the other person.

Comment: @tempdevnova please don't arbitrarily change examples in comments. If you have a concrete problem that requires solution describe it unequivocally in the question body, otherwise if this is just hypothetical at least create a coherent question with a well defined set of parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you can change email addresses for your current account by visiting the settings page https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/142369 no need to create a new one.

Otherwise you can request accounts to be merged. See the help page about requesting to merge accounts https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Never witnessed the process myself, so not sure how reputation is handled, it may be preserved, but I'm not sure.

As for using bounties I'd strongly discourage it. This may at first seem like a semi-legitimate usage, but is considered a voting irregularity, and will most likely trip the anti-fraud system.

Your reputation in a certain site is a reflection of your knowledge on that area of expertise, and a representation of the level of respect entrusted to you by the community, it is personal and non-transferable.

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373374/is-there-a-way-to-transfer-stack-overflow-points-reputation

Comment: Let's forget the actual cases and just focus on the general question: "Is it okay to transfer reputation to another account using bounties?" From your answer I got that using the bounty system would fall into the grey zone (which I think also makes sense since we are not actually generating new reputation, only transferring). Is that correct?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a "grey zone", it is squarely against the rules . reputation you gained represents your knowledge and the level of respect entrusted to you by a community, it is non interchangeable and transferable.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373374/is-there-a-way-to-transfer-stack-overflow-points-reputation